# Get the tail of a string in C

Tags: c

I have a string, like "`100110000111001100010001100011001100100`" .

If I need to get the tail of this string, meaning everything but the first element, 
do I have to copy each char to the new array, starting from the second element (O(n)),

or is there a faster way to do this, like somehow magically shift pointers 1 place to the right or a built in function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just make a char* that points to the index you need.

```
char *p = "100110000111001100010001100011001100100";
char *tail = &p[1]; //&p[1] is the same as p+1
printf("p = %s\ntail = %s\n",p,tail);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need to make any modifications to the string then you can just give the original pointer plus 1, otherwise you will need to copy.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing magical about it. A pointer to a string, like a pointer to an array, is just the address of the first element.

Basic pointer arithmetic, take your existing pointer, increment it (`p++`), and you have a pointer to the "tail" of your string.